# I am trying to install Kivy again it is shows this warning

Tags: kivy, warnings, kivymd

[this error and warning is showing when I tried to install Kivy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAwIH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Python 3.10 is still currently relatively new and library developers need to recompile their package to the newest version, there is currently no way to install `Kivy` and its dependencies on Python 3.10 . I suggest you downgrade to Python 3.9 or even 3.8 for the installation to succeed.

Comment: now i am using Py 3.9.2  this error i have got ->[ERROR: Could not build wheels for kivy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects]  how to counter this error

Comment: Try installing the latest cutting-edge version from [master](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/tree/master) using `python -m pip install "kivy[base] @ https://github.com/kivy/kivy/archive/master.zip"`, it should work